# \[INS-30014] Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS

Tags: oracle19c

On migrating my local Oracle DB on Windows, from 11g to 19c, while running the `setup.exe`, I got a:
`[INS-30014] Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS`

Answer (score 33):

In my case, I needed to open my hosts file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) and comment out the following:

```
# 192.168.0.111 host.docker.internal  
# 192.168.0.111 gateway.docker.internal  
# 127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
```

These seemed to be remnants of my old docker installation which has since been removed.

Comment: Thank you, saved me here!

Comment: yep that was my issue!

Comment: Yesssssssss!!!!

Comment: yeeah it's work

Comment: I'm running windows 10 through Parallels on Mac Intel and this worked thanks! Any idea as to why would this work though?

Comment: thanks, could you share how you found out this was the issue?

Answer (score 7):

In my case this was a permissions issue on the Oracle Home directory. If your Windows PC name is >= 16 characters in length, the name of the administrators group is affected, because only the first 15 characters are included. The mismatch between that first part of the name and the full name is what was causing the issue. DESKTOP-ASUS-ROG vs. DESKTOP-ASUS-RO in my case (notice the missing G). I renamed the PC to DESKTOPASUS, restarted the machine, and it worked without issue. The name discrepancy was apparent when looking at the security configuration of the folder when my system name was over max.

You can get your PC name by running `hostname` from the command line. If it's >= 16 characters, rename the PC to be <= 15 characters, and restart.

The underlying issue is indirectly discussed here in a different context:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/naming-conventions-for-computer-domain-site-ou

`Maximum name length: 15 characters.`

Comment: This was also my problem.

Comment: This worked for me too, Thanks a lot it saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 5):

I tried other solutions from Stackoverflow, but none worked in my case.
Here is the fix:

- Go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections
- Disable

  - vEthernet (Docker)
  - vEthernet (Default switch)
- resume the install
- re-enable both disabled vEthernet.

Comment: This helped. Disabling only the two you specified did not work. What I did instead, was to disable all Ethernet connections and then it worked. Thanks

Comment: for some reaseon this worked

Answer (score 2):

By installing the software first and then running dbca to create the db I got it to work,

Comment: This worked for me. Run "Setup.exe" -> Select "Set Up Software Only". 
Once that completes, go to ORACLE_HOME\bin
Run as administrator "dbca.bat" (I got an error if I didn't run it as administrator)