# //[INS-30014] Unable to check whether the location specified is on CFS 2022

Tags: oracle19c

I know there is a corresponding topic but I can not really find a solution, can someone help me? I have tried all the solutions mentioned in the corresponding topic but I still get the same error.

**Reference of the topic:**

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62836198/ins-30014-unable-to-check-whether-the-location-specified-is-on-cfs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

you need to make new copy exactly same with hosts and replace it with another but without docker ip or kybernetes

Comment: Thanks. Note that you have do this with Admin privileges.